# how can i fix this error on React-native project on Appcenter?

Tags: android, react-native, build, appcenter

I've tryed to bluid on the appcenter the app, this was my first error was the version of JAVA( Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.), so I installed the https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk

and now i'm facing this error:

```
##[section]Starting: Build
##[section]Starting: Initialize job
Agent name: 'Hosted Agent'
Agent machine name: 'Mac-1675090393322'
Current agent version: '2.214.1'
##[group]Operating System
macOS
11.7.2
20G1020
##[endgroup]
##[group]Runner Image
Image: macos-11
Version: 20230117.2
Included Software: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/macOS-11/20230117.2/images/macos/macos-11-Readme.md
Image Release: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/releases/tag/macOS-11%2F20230117.2
##[endgroup]
##[group]Runner Image Provisioner
2.0.98.1
##[endgroup]
Current image version: '20230117.2'
Agent running as: 'runner'
Prepare build directory.
Set build variables.
Download all required tasks.
Downloading task: PowerShell (2.212.0)
Downloading task: Bash (3.214.0)
Downloading task: CmdLine (1.1.3)
Downloading task: ShellScript (2.212.0)
Downloading task: CmdLine (2.212.0)
Downloading task: Gradle (1.128.0)
Downloading task: CopyFiles (2.211.0)
Downloading task: PublishBuildArtifacts (1.211.0)
Downloading task: AppCenterDistribute (3.214.0)
Checking job knob settings.
   Knob: AgentToolsDirectory = /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache Source: ${AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY} 
Finished checking job knob settings.
Start tracking orphan processes.
##[section]Finishing: Initialize job
##[section]Starting: Checkout app-mobile@staging to s
==============================================================================
Task         : Get sources
Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
Version      : 1.0.0
Author       : Microsoft
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
==============================================================================
Syncing repository: app-mobile (ExternalGit)
##[command]git version
git version 2.39.1
##[command]git lfs version
git-lfs/3.3.0 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.19.3)
##[command]git init "/Users/runner/work/1/s"
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/runner/work/1/s/.git/
hint: 
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint: 
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint: 
hint:   git branch -m <name>
##[command]git remote add origin https://github.com/test-io/app-mobile.git
##[command]git config gc.auto 0
##[command]git config --get-all http.https://github.com/test-io/app-mobile.git.extraheader
##[command]git config --get-all http.extraheader
##[command]git config --get-regexp .*extraheader
##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
##[command]git config http.version HTTP/1.1
##[command]git remote set-url origin https://***:***@github.com/test-io/app-mobile.git
##[command]git remote set-url --push origin https://***:***@github.com/test-io/app-mobile.git
##[command]git lfs install --local
Updated Git hooks.
Git LFS initialized.
##[command]git config remote.origin.lfsurl https://***:***@github.com/test-io/app-mobile.git/info/lfs
##[command]git config remote.origin.lfspushurl https://***:***@github.com/test-io/app-mobile.git/info/lfs
##[command]git fetch --force --tags --prune --prune-tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
remote: Enumerating objects: 7768, done.        
remote: Counting objects:   0% (1/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:   1% (16/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:   2% (31/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:   3% (46/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:   4% (61/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:   5% (76/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:   6% (91/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:   7% (106/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:   8% (121/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:   9% (136/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  10% (151/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  11% (166/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  12% (181/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  13% (196/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  14% (211/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  15% (226/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  16% (241/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  17% (256/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  18% (271/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  19% (286/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  20% (301/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  21% (316/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  22% (331/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  23% (346/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  24% (361/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  25% (376/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  26% (391/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  27% (406/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  28% (421/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  29% (436/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  30% (451/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  31% (466/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  32% (481/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  33% (496/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  34% (511/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  35% (526/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  36% (541/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  37% (556/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  38% (571/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  39% (586/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  40% (601/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  41% (616/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  42% (631/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  43% (646/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  44% (661/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  45% (676/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  46% (691/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  47% (706/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  48% (721/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  49% (736/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  50% (751/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  51% (766/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  52% (781/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  53% (796/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  54% (811/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  55% (826/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  56% (841/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  57% (856/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  58% (871/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  59% (886/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  60% (901/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  61% (916/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  62% (931/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  63% (946/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  64% (961/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  65% (976/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  66% (991/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  67% (1006/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  68% (1021/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  69% (1036/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  70% (1051/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  71% (1066/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  72% (1081/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  73% (1096/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  74% (1111/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  75% (1126/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  76% (1141/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  77% (1156/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  78% (1171/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  79% (1186/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  80% (1201/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  81% (1216/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  82% (1231/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  83% (1246/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  84% (1261/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  85% (1276/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  86% (1291/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  87% (1306/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  88% (1321/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  89% (1336/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  90% (1351/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  91% (1366/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  92% (1381/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  93% (1396/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  94% (1411/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  95% (1426/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  96% (1441/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  97% (1456/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  98% (1471/1501)        
remote: Counting objects:  99% (1486/1501)        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1501/1501)        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1501/1501), done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (570/570), done.        
Receiving objects:  98% (7613/7768)
remote: Total 7768 (delta 989), reused 1125 (delta 913), pack-reused 6267        
Receiving objects: 100% (7768/7768), 13.60 MiB | 27.15 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4515/4515), done.
From https://github.com/test-io/app-mobile
 * [new branch]      dev                  -> origin/dev
 * [new branch]      develop_bk           -> origin/develop_bk
 * [new branch]      fix-npm-build-error  -> origin/fix-npm-build-error
 * [new branch]      fixIntermediateStops -> origin/fixIntermediateStops
 * [new branch]      main                 -> origin/main
 * [new branch]      pick-up-point        -> origin/pick-up-point
 * [new branch]      staging              -> origin/staging
##[command]git checkout 7887c0f5c3331ddf80738738a721561dca8ac8a0 -- .lfsconfig
error: pathspec '.lfsconfig' did not match any file(s) known to git
##[command]git lfs fetch origin 7887c0f5c3331ddf80738738a721561dca8ac8a0
fetch: Fetching reference 7887c0f5c3331ddf80738738a721561dca8ac8a0
##[command]git checkout --progress --force 7887c0f5c3331ddf80738738a721561dca8ac8a0
HEAD is now at 7887c0f Merge branch 'staging' of https://github.com/test-io/app-mobile into staging
##[command]git submodule sync --recursive
##[command]git submodule update --init --force --recursive
##[command]git remote set-url origin https://github.com/test-io/app-mobile.git
##[command]git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/test-io/app-mobile.git
##[command]git config --unset-all remote.origin.lfsurl
##[command]git config --unset-all remote.origin.lfspushurl
##[section]Finishing: Checkout app-mobile@staging to s
##[section]Starting: Install build scripts
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
Version      : 2.212.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
[command]/usr/local/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/Users/runner/work/_temp/60981a72-50ee-4163-a24c-89ee83d5914e.ps1'
Reinstalling Gradle init script plugins from /Users/runner/runners/2.214.1/scripts/gradle-init-script-plugins...
##[section]Finishing: Install build scripts
##[section]Starting: Select Node.js Version v2
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.214.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Formatted command: exec bash '/Users/runner/runners/2.214.1/scripts/select-node-version.sh' node16
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
[command]/bin/bash /Users/runner/work/_temp/5fb58e04-a0b5-4a75-9f03-271e187e5641.sh
v16.19.0 is already installed.
Now using node v16.19.0 (npm v8.19.3)
default -> v16.19.0 *
Node version: v16.19.0
npm version: 8.19.3
##[section]Finishing: Select Node.js Version v2
##[section]Starting: yarn/npm install
==============================================================================
Task         : Command Line
Description  : Run a command line with arguments
Version      : 1.1.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613735)
==============================================================================
[command]/bin/sh -c if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then { yarn install --network-timeout=600000 && yarn list --depth=0; } else npm install; fi
(node:2298) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2298) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2298) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2298) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2298) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2298) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2298) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.11: Repository was moved to @react-native-masked-view/masked-view
npm WARN deprecated @aws-amplify/ui@2.0.7: Versions '1.x' and '2.x' of '@aws-amplify/ui' have been deprecated. Please visit https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/ for the current version of Amplify UI.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

added 2236 packages, and audited 2237 packages in 1m

156 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
##[section]Finishing: yarn/npm install
##[section]Starting: Pre Build Script
==============================================================================
Task         : Shell script
Description  : Run a shell script using Bash
Version      : 2.212.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/shell-script
==============================================================================
##[error]Not found scriptPath: /Users/runner/work/1/s/appcenter-pre-build.sh
##[error]Bash failed with error: Not found scriptPath: /Users/runner/work/1/s/appcenter-pre-build.sh
##[section]Finishing: Pre Build Script
##[section]Starting: Checkout app-mobile@staging to s
==============================================================================
Task         : Get sources
Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
Version      : 1.0.0
Author       : Microsoft
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
==============================================================================
Cleaning any cached credential from repository: app-mobile (ExternalGit)
##[section]Finishing: Checkout app-mobile@staging to s
##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
Cleaning up task key
Start cleaning up orphan processes.
##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
##[section]Finishing: Build
```

I've tried to add this org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home on my gradle.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppCenter build runner has predefined some variables for users to configure their build with.

You can set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to `$(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)` in your build config on AppCenter.